# Return URL query parameters

Tags: apache, clean-urls

Is there any way or tools that can return the get parameters from a clean URL? For example:

```
www.website.com/cat/1
```

How this URL look like before clean it?

---

**UPDATE: Example**

The original URL before clean is like this:

```
http://example.com/wiki/index.php?title=Page_title
```

When clean it becomes like this:

```
http://example.com/wiki/Page_title
```

Is there a tool that I could give the clean URL and return the non-clean?

Comment: what do you mean by "returning"

Comment: I mean return the origin URL before it become clean

Comment: you mean you want to remove the get parameters from the url?

Comment: no I want to know this parameters if I have a Clean URL and I don't have access to the server

Comment: Hi. I think you should check this on Wiki:    http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_engine

Comment: So you want to know the POST parameters?

Comment: let me explain with example :

Comment: So basically you want the entire url (including get parameters) to show in your navigation bar

Comment: not like that all I need to know how the URL look like before it convert to clean URL